# Qt QCombobox popup inconsistent position

Tags: c++, qt

I have searched far and wide and cannot find anything online about my issue even though it seems rather trivial, and i feel like there's just something I'm missing, so I apologise if the answer is apparent.

However, when I use a QComboBox in Qt, When I click on it instead of dropping down like I want it to, it shows the popup with the current selected item as the origin. If that doesn't make sense this is what I am referring to:

[image]

It shows the popup starting at the current selected item where the button is. I just want it to drop downwards like any other normal combobox! How can i Achieve this? If i make it editable it drops down exactly how i want it, but i don't want it to be editable!

Does anyone know what's up?

Edit:
    I am running Windows 10

Comment: Are you using a specific style for your application then (like Plastique?). The default one doesn't show this behavior for me, and doesn't look like the picture.

Comment: Looks like it's using CleanLooks.

Comment: I tried using Fusion and no luck reproducing. As it may be due to a lot of variables (like is the combobox centered in a vertical layout?) it's best if there's a basic code reproducing the problem available. Also, the popup can be customized like this: `myWidget->setStyleSheet("QComboBox:dropdown { max-height: 200px;}")`, as it looks like the only reason the popup is going up is because of its height;

Comment: What happens if you only have 4 items?